# C# WPF Интегрирование элементов в Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть основное окно `MainWindow.xaml`. В нём есть контейнер

`<StackPanel Name="stackPlace"/>`

и есть Файл `TodoForm.xaml`с заготовленным элементом. Вопрос звучит так, как мне создать элемент по шаблону TodoForm  и затолкать его в stackPlace?

Comment: Вообще вот сама задача, есть бд с списком дел. у дела есть название и маркер, выполнено оно или нет, нужно 1) загрузить все Todo из бд и вывести на экран, 2) создавать новый Todo(соответственно и интерфейс для него)

Comment: Не совсем понятно что там у вас, но, видимо, вам просто нужен UserControl

Comment: Ну к раз это задача для UserControl